# How to use Aggregator options such as completionSize, completionTimeout with split-aggregate

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I can use an aggregator with completionSize and completionTimeout as below:

```
    from("direct:aggregate")
    .routeId("aggregate")
    .aggregate(constant(true), new JSONAggregator())
        .completionSize(500)
        .completionTimeout(3000)
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .log("${body}")
    .end();
```

However, when I use an aggregationStrategy in conjunction with a splitter, I do not get these options. How can I implement aggregator options with a splitter?

Comment: Could you add to the question what you think the code should be (including the split)? I just want to see what you're expecting to work

Comment: @Sam i am hoping for some way to provide these options when doing a split aggregate!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use these options with the [Split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html). **The Splitter combined with an aggregation strategy simply re-aggregates all the parts of the input message it has splitted before.**

Example: Split a message with 5000 lines, transform each line and re-aggregate these lines according to the strategy.

**Because the aggragtion size is defined by the input message, you can't use any other aggregate completion options.**

However, what you can do is, to use the Split EIP without aggregation strategy followed later in the processing by an independant [Aggregate EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/aggregate-eip.html). Then you can configure the aggregator as you like.